# VSCode: Warning; Debugee Target Architecture not detected, assuming x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, visual-studio-code, clang++

I have been trying for a few hours to solve this issue but couldn't find any solution.

**System informaiton**

Version: macOS BigSur 11.1

VScode: 1.52.1

C/C++: 1.1.3

When setting the "externalConsole" in the launch.json file to false, the debugging works perfectly but since I want to input data while debugging this option doesn't work for me. I was hoping someone could help me out here with what I am missing?

**launch.json**

```
    {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

      {
        "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "lldb",
        "preLaunchTask": "clang++ build active file"
      }
    ]
  }
```

**task.json**

```
 {
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "clang++ build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
      "args": [
        "-std=c++17",
        "-stdlib=libc++",
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

**Code that I am trying to debug**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Node 
{
public:
    int datum; // data component
    // if we store address of int type we put int*
    // if we store address of double we put double*
    // similary for string*
    // now we waant to store pointer in Node*
    Node* pNext;
    Node() // contstructor
    {
        datum = 0;
        pNext = nullptr;
    }

    Node(int Datum, Node* link)
    {
        datum = Datum;
        pNext = link;
    }
    // sorted linked list: where the data component is in ascending order

};

class SortedLinkedList
{
private:
    Node* pHead;
public:
    SortedLinkedList()
    {
        pHead = nullptr;
    }

    SortedLinkedList(Node* link)
    {
        pHead = link;
    }

    bool isEmpty() // to check if the list is empty
    {
        return(pHead == nullptr); // if true the list is empty
    }

    void createList() // how many nodes do we want to have in out list? dynamic or static: here we do dynamic
    {
        cout << "Enter the number of nodes that you want to have in the list: " << endl;
        int numberOfNodes; // storing our number of nodes the user asks
        cin >> numberOfNodes;

        // now we will have two auxilary nodes that will use to create 
        Node* pCurrentNode;
        Node* pNewNode;

        cout << "Enter the value to store in the 0th node: " << endl;
        // to store this value we declare another variable
        int inputValue; // to store value enterd by the user
        cin >> inputValue;

        pNewNode = new Node(inputValue, nullptr); // make sure what we have done here
        pHead = pNewNode; // store the value of new node in head
        pCurrentNode = pNewNode; // store the value of newNode in Currentnode

        int count = 0; // for the while loop

        while(count != (numberOfNodes-1))
        {
            cout << "Enter the value to store in the " << count + 1 << " node; " << endl;
            // count 1 = second node as the first is pHead
            cin >> inputValue;
            pNewNode = new Node(inputValue, nullptr); // second node: So we want to link this new node to the current node by storing the address of our new node
            pCurrentNode->pNext = pNewNode;
            pCurrentNode = pNewNode;
            count++;
        }

    }
    Node* searchLinkedList(Node* pHead, int x) // search linked list program
    {
        Node* pPrevious = nullptr; // initialized anotehr variable
        Node* pCurrent = pHead;

        while(pCurrent!=nullptr && pCurrent -> datum < x)
        {
            pPrevious = pCurrent;
            pCurrent = pCurrent -> pNext; // assign teh address of the next node
        }
        return pPrevious;
    }

    void printLinkedList()
        {
            cout << "Our linked list is as follows: " << endl;
            for(Node* p = pHead; p!= nullptr; p = p->pNext)
            // for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) the above code is similar to this one
            {
                cout << p->datum << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    SortedLinkedList list1;
    cout << list1.isEmpty() << endl; // 1 means the list is empty therefore, we have to create a list
    
    list1.createList();
    list1.printLinkedList();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd got the same error as you do.
Luckily, I've found solution somewhere else.
Here comes it!

1. You can install the extension "CodeLLDB"
2. Here are my tasks.json and launch.json

#### tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang++"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the [website](https://blog.csdn.net/fujz123/article/details/104426121) where I got my solution.